# Axios false 404 error

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I'm having an issue where I think [axios](/questions/tagged/axios) is querying the wrong URL just before query is sent.

```
getShows : function(){
  if( ! this.query ) return false;
  var getURL = this.makeUrlFromObject(this.query);
  console.log('getURL', getURL);
  var self = this;
  axios.get(getURL).then(function(response){
    console.log('response.data', response.data)
    self.shows = response.data;
  });
},
makeUrlFromObject : function(query){
  var queryArray = [];
  for (var prop in query) {
    if(!query.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
    queryArray.push(prop + "=" + query[prop]);
  }
  var url = this.apiUrl + '?' + queryArray.join('&');
  return url;
},
...
```

Running the `getShows` returns the following in the console:

```
1. getURL /api/all?date=20180131

2. GET http://website.dev/shows/false 404 (Not Found)                     false:1

3. response.data (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
```

I can't seem to diagnose where this `false:1` is coming from. The request and response are both working, just this extra request seems to crop up from nowhere.

Comment: What's the content of `this.query`?

Comment: @DominicTobias its a key value object with the current URL query string, i.e. if you are on a URL with `?age=10` it would be `{ age : 10 }`

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. Following the ajax request, an image element is created on the page.

The response (not shown) happened to include an image file that was loaded into 2 of the 3 objects. The 3rd didn't have an image, so it came back as `{ image : false }`.

When this was then used to create an image template, it was coming back as:

```
<div style="background-image:url(false)">
```

So the console came back with a get request for 'false', which 404d.